# centering links inside html5 nav

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, center, nav

I need to center all links content (all numbers in this case) inside HTML `<nav>` element.

the css :

```
section nav {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    width: 598px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

section nav a {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

the html :

```
<section>
    <nav>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-0/">0</a>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-1/">1</a>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-2/">2</a>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-3/">3</a>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-4/">4</a>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-5/">5</a>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-6/">6</a>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-7/">7</a>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-8/">8</a>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-9/">9</a>
            <a href="https://puaction.com/pua-10/">10</a>
        </nav>
</section>
```

the jsFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/EEtD4/

:)

Thanks !

Comment: Have you try text-align:center; on section nav a ?

Comment: yep... not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/EEtD4/1/

added this

```
section nav {
   text-align: center;
}
```

changed

```
section nav a {
   float: left;  /* removed this */
}
```

---

EDIT

Also , to have the links be vertically centered as well I did this

```
section nav {
      line-height: 28px;
}
```

instead of

```
  height: 28px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EEtD4/2/

Comment: So funny ! I was just about to ask about vertical alignment (in a new ticket) and you answered both questions :) Many Thanks !